# .NET C# Methods and Types Issue

Tags: c#, .net, object

I'm struggling with this question.

I am trying create a contextmenu in another class and link it to the Datagrid. Here is sample code to recreate what I'm trying to do:

```
  namespace Context_Menu_Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem();
            mi1.Header = "Test1";
            cm.Items.Add(mi1);
            //This Works
            DG1.ContextMenu = cm;

            //THIS DOESN'T WORK
            DG1.ContextMenu = new Menus.Context_Menus.generate_datagrid_context_menu();
        }
    }
}

namespace Menus
{
    public class Context_Menus
    {
        public ContextMenu generate_datagrid_context_menu()
        {
            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem();
            mi1.Header = "Test1";
            cm.Items.Add(mi1);
            return cm;
        }
    }
}
```

> Error 1   'Menus.Context_Menus.generate_datagrid_context_menu()' is a
>   'method' but is used like a
>   'type'    W:\Test_Code\Context_Menu_Test\MainWindow.xaml.cs   33  55  Context_Menu_Test

Comment: `new Menus.Context_Menus` needs to be `(new Menus.Context_Menus())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the right *syntax* would be:

```
DG1.ContextMenu = (new Menus.Context_Menus()).generate_datagrid_context_menu();
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
var menu = new Menus.Context_Menus();
DG1.ContextMenu = menu.generate_datagrid_context_menu();
```

Basically you need an *instance* of the `Context_Menus` class in order to call a non-static *method* on it.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now! This will help me in several different places.

Answer (score 1):

`generate_datagrid_context_menu` is an instance method, so you need to call the `Menus.Context_Menus` constructor, then call `generate_datagrid_context_menu` on the resulting object:

```
var menus = new Menus.Context_Menus();
DG1.ContextMenu = menus.generate_datagrid_context_menu();
```

Alternatively, you could make the `generate_datagrid_context_menu` method static:

```
public static ContextMenu generate_datagrid_context_menu()
{
    ...
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
DG1.ContextMenu = Menus.Context_Menus.generate_datagrid_context_menu();
```

Answer (score 1):

DG1.ContextMenu = new Menus.Context_Menus.generate_datagrid_context_menu();

This line is actually doing the following:

```
type = Menus.Context_Menus.generate_datagrid_context_menu;  
DG1.ContextMenu = new type();
```

since `Menus.Context_Menus.generate_datagrid_context_menu();`  is a method not a type so the compiler would not like it.

```
var menus = new Menus.Context_Menus();
DG1.ContextMenu = menus.generate_datagrid_context_menu();
```

is what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

If your class `Context_Menus` has no member, you can make it static.

Don't use `new` for a static class !

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // ...
    DG1.ContextMenu = Menus.Context_Menus.generate_datagrid_context_menu();
}

namespace Menus
{
    public static class Context_Menus
    {
        public static ContextMenu generate_datagrid_context_menu()
        {
            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem();
            mi1.Header = "Test1";
            cm.Items.Add(mi1);
            return cm;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: other answers force to use `new` for `Context_Menus`. Obviously, `Context_Menus` no need to be a instance class, but must be a static class (if no more method). I'm the opposite of the other answers.

Comment: Thank you for your alternative answer - this is what I knew how to do, it was for when there were other methods that I wasn't sure.